# iOS Passbook how to work with

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I try to work with passbook. SO as i understand from guide i need to create certificate, generate json and than i need to upload passbook to my server, after that if i open page in safari from iPhone i can see my own passbook in passbook app.
But is it way to get passbook on button click on my app without opening safari?
Please, correct me if i've error on work logic with passbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You will need a server that can create the pass, and your app will need to call your server to request the pass. Then your app needs to use the PKPassViewController to display the pass to the user so the user can add it to their Passbook. See the Apple Passbook Programming Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Introduction.html